# Como muestro las imagenes guardadas en mi BD con ruta

Tags: php, html

Yo lo que quiero es mostrar las imagenes que tengo en una ruta...esa ruta esta guardada en mi base de datos...este es el codigo que sirve para visualizar las imagenes o eso creo pstd=ahora si es el codigo correcto

````
include 'conexion.php'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DATOS GUARDADOS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Imagen</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT url_imagen FROM productos";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
            if ($resultado) {
                while ($data = $query) {

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img height="500px" src="<?php?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
        <button><a href="index.php">Ingresar</a></button>
    </center>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No detallas demasiado sobre la tabla con los datos, pero te doy el método de como hacer lo que pides: mostrar la imagen guardada en tu base de datos.

- Con un SELECT buscas el registro de la  imagen  ( mysqli_query() )
- Lees la columna donde se almacena la url de la imagen
- luego en el elmento img de la página  web pones el atributo src al
  valor buscado con el prefijo img/ (es el que usas en tu código) con
  el habitual src=""
  Este es el algoritmo de la solución, con los datos de la pregunta no puedo concretar más, pero seguro que lo puedes aplicar.

Comment: me podrias explicar como seria eso? pstd=me equivoque de codigo jaja

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a stack

Por lo que vi lo único que te faltaría seria poner **"$resultado"** en src, adelantándome al problema, quizás deberías poner un **"where"** con una condicion en la consulta por que te traería la lista completa de url.

espero que te ayude y éxitos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DATOS GUARDADOS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Imagen</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT url_imagen FROM productos WHERE condicion = condicion";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
            if ($resultado) {
                while ($data = $query) {

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img height="500px" src="<?php echo($resultado); ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
        <button><a href="index.php">Ingresar</a></button>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias pero igual no me funciono :( pero igual muchas gracias por la ayuda :)